# The first build on TFS - and I get lots of compile errors. Third party assemblies cannot be located

Tags: tfs

I am trying to run my first build using TFS 2010. The build fails because it cannot locate the third party assemblies such as AntiXSSLibrary.dll.
What do I need to do to fix this?

Comment: Have you got a "Lib" folder that contains all your 3rd party libraries? If so, is the lib folder in the workspace? Are the references resolving to the assemblies in that lib folder when you build the project locally?

Answer (score 0):

See http://www.ewaldhofman.nl/post/2010/02/09/Where-is-the-AdditionalReferencePath-in-TFS-2010.aspx

Comment: So for MSBuild Arguments I should specify where my dlls are? For exxample, /p:ReferencePath=”C:\Documents and Settings\geoffreypayne\My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\MVC\SHP\SHP\bin”

Comment: You have to point to the directory where the binaries are on the build server. I normally add the binaries to source control, include the folder in the workspace mapping of the build, and then build the reference path with the SourceDirectory argument. See http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tfsbuild/thread/f6ae617f-8da3-4d2c-83b1-5ecb441d2d83 for an example

Comment: How do I include the "folder in the workspace mapping of the build"? I put the binaries in source control and now I get messages that say "The type or namespace name 'Mvc' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?)"